# How can i save my listbox to ObservableCollection<>

Tags: c#, observable

MyDoc.cs

```
public class MyDoc
{

  public string Private {set;get;}
  public string Public  {set;get;}
}
```

MyFind.cs

```
public class MyFind
{
 public string Find {set;get;}
 public string News  {set;get;}

 private ObservableCollection<MyDoc> _list;
 public ObservableCollection<MyDoc> List
 {
       get
        {
             if (_list == null)
             {
                  _list = new ObservableCollection<MyDoc>();
             }
             return _list;
        }
       set
        {
              if (_list != value)
              {
                   _list = value;
              }
        }
 }
}
```

In Page1.xaml.cs

```
MyFind myfind = new MyFind();
myfind.Find = Findtextbox.Text;//string = string
myfind.News = Newstextbox.Text;//string = string
myfind.List = ???
```

ObservableCollection = listbox1.??? (??? = Items,or ItemsSources,or something,...May I use Convert ?)<------------ I don't have any ideas ! Help me !

Answer (score 0):

If you've set the ItemsSource property to something like a List you could execute the following code:

```
MyFind myFind = new MyFind();

var myDocs = simpleListBox.ItemsSource as List<MyDoc>;
myDocs.ForEach(d => myFind.List.Add(d));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for the [ItemsSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property:

```
MyFind myfind = new MyFind();
myfind.Find = Findtextbox.Text;
myfind.News = Newstextbox.Text;
myfind.List = new ObservableCollection<MyDoc>(listbox1.ItemsSource.Cast<MyDoc>());
```

Here I'm creating a new ObservableCollection of MyDoc objects, and to the constructor I'm passing an IEnumerable of MyDoc items. Because the listbox1.ItemsSource property returns an untyped IEnumerable, I'm first casting it using LINQ to the correct type.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to do this is just beyond me! If you use an ObservableCollection with Binding and add remove T (items) from your listbox, the observable collection will get updated. Something inline with this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<MyData> List { get; set; }
}

public class MyView : UserControl
{
    public MyView()
    {
        DataContext = new MyViewModel();
    }
}

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding List}" />
```